# Update the Lambda function to use the new Layer Version using Boto3

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3

I have a lambda function and that lambda is using the layers. I am creating a boto3 to update the lambda function to use the latest layer. I can see only this(see code below) in the AWS boto3 document (https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/lambda.html#Lambda.Client.update_function_code) .

```
response = client.update_function_code(
    FunctionName='string',
    ZipFile=b'bytes',
    S3Bucket='string',
    S3Key='string',
    S3ObjectVersion='string',
    Publish=True|False,
    DryRun=True|False,
    RevisionId='string'
)
```

I cannot see the layer field there to point the new version/update.

TIA.

Comment: added answer @Arun

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`update_function_code` is function to changes in code. You have to use `update_function_configuration` to update layer or any other configuration

```
response = client.update_function_configuration(
    FunctionName='string',
    Role='string',
    Handler='string',
    Description='string',
    Timeout=123,
    MemorySize=123,
    VpcConfig={
        'SubnetIds': [
            'string',
        ],
        'SecurityGroupIds': [
            'string',
        ]
    },
    Environment={
        'Variables': {
            'string': 'string'
        }
    },
    Runtime='nodejs'|'nodejs4.3'|'nodejs6.10'|'nodejs8.10'|'nodejs10.x'|'nodejs12.x'|'java8'|'java11'|'python2.7'|'python3.6'|'python3.7'|'python3.8'|'dotnetcore1.0'|'dotnetcore2.0'|'dotnetcore2.1'|'dotnetcore3.1'|'nodejs4.3-edge'|'go1.x'|'ruby2.5'|'ruby2.7'|'provided',
    DeadLetterConfig={
        'TargetArn': 'string'
    },
    KMSKeyArn='string',
    TracingConfig={
        'Mode': 'Active'|'PassThrough'
    },
    RevisionId='string',
    Layers=[
        'string',
    ]
)
```

reference : https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/lambda.html#Lambda.Client.update_function_configuration